# Example for safe and unsafe downcast?

Tags: java, casting

When is a downcast unsafe and safe?

Safe(think so) : [source - [here]](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ309_014.htm)

```
class Useful {
  public void f() {}
  public void g() {}
}

class MoreUseful extends Useful {
  public void f() {}
  public void g() {}
  public void u() {}
  public void v() {}
  public void w() {}
}

public class RTTI {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Useful[] x = {
      new Useful(),
      new MoreUseful()
    };
    x[0].f();
    x[1].g();
    // Compile time: method not found in Useful:
    //! x[1].u();
    ((MoreUseful)x[1]).u(); // Downcast/RTTI
    ((MoreUseful)x[0]).u(); // Exception thrown
  }
}
```

Can anyone give example for a unsafe downcast?

Comment: If you make the functions `virtual` you won't have to worry about casting at all.  That's the beauty of polymorphism.

Comment: Question is unclear, you already provided an example of unsafe casting...

Comment: You mean other than the example in your post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time the downcast would lose information it is unsafe. For example,

```
float pi = (float) Math.PI; // <-- unsafe cast double to float.
int i = (int) Long.MAX_VALUE; // <-- unsafe long to int
int min = (int) Long.MIN_VALUE; // <-- also unsafe long to int
```

Perhaps you meant from an OO perspective,

```
Long l = (Long) ((Object) "Hello"); // <-- unsafe String to Long casting.
```

Comment: Thanks. Any example for a safe downcast?

Comment: A safe downcast is when the value would fit. `long v = 0; int i = (int) v;`